# Determine addresses and page table size

Tags: operating-system, size, memory-address, virtual-address-space, page-tables

I know that this question has been asked many times but I still feel I struggle with it.

```
Given: 
physical memory: 2^20
32-bit system
page size: 2^10
```

I need to determine what a physical and virtual addresses would look like as well as calculate the page table size.

I am not sure what I have is correct but this is what I have got so far:

```
->Virtual address would look like (22 bits specifying page #)(10 bit specifying offset)
->Physical address would look like** (10 bits specifying frame #)(10 bits specifying offset)
```

The number of page entries is 2^20/2^10=2^10

How do I calculate the page table size? I am confused since each PTE has both virtual and physical addresses. Would it be number of page entries*(physical address+virtual address)?
How would it be different if  I have the present bit set?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Size of page table depends on what metadata bits you hold for each entry (valid dirty, etc..)

Basically the size would be: `(num_of_pages)*(num_of_bits_for_frame_number + meta_bits)`.
Ex. `(valid bit): 2^22*(10 + 1)`

Comment: Thank you! May I please ask you to verify whether my other logic of calculations was correct. I want to make sure I understand it correctly. I would be very grateful

Comment: Virtual and physical address will look like you described.
Number of page entries is `2^32 / 2^10 = 2^22`.
Remember that pages are associated to virtual memory and frames to physical.